Can Azure AI Search retrieve all the SQL table records' index from big data?
I am using azure ai search and llm to get the response from sql table against user text query. but when user ask like "provide me the total average salary of employees" so in this case azure ai search should retrieve all the salary records and llm calculate the average. but azure ai search failed to retrieved the all records. Is there any technique to sort out this problem or I should move to another NLQ methods.
Search Answers: [] Value: 

Search Score: 1.261305
 Reranker Score: 1.3793658018112183
 Claim ID: "C004" 
Policy Number: "P225166"
 Claim Date: "2024-03-04"
 Insured Entity: "Williams PLC"
 Claim Amount: "1,644,928.00"
 Claim Description: "Always amount begin."
 Loss Adjuster Report: "path/to/loss_adjuster_report_004.pdf" 
Claim Status: "Approved"
 Claim Settlement Date: null
 Settlement Amount: "76,928.00"

I tried to get the response of "provide me the total average salary of employees" but azure ai search provide me only one record.

share your  index in text formate .

provide me the sum of claim amount all the claim ids?
Search Answers: []
Value:
Search Score: 1.261305
Reranker Score: 1.3793658018112183
Claim ID: "C004"
Policy Number: "P225166"
Claim Date: "2024-03-04"
Insured Entity: "Williams PLC"
Claim Amount: "1,644,928.00"
Claim Description: "Always amount begin."
Loss Adjuster Report: "path/to/loss_adjuster_report_004.pdf"
Claim Status: "Approved"
Claim Settlement Date: null
Settlement Amount: "76,928.00"

Update in json format in the above questions with input data and index output and index as well. Thank you

Semantic search will only return verbatim statements from your index. It cannot calculate the average from tabular data. See documentation for Returning a semantic answer.

A semantic answer is a substructure of a semantic query response. It consists of one or more verbatim passages from a search document, formulated as an answer to a query that looks like a question. To return an answer, phrases or sentences must exist in a search document that have the language characteristics of an answer, and the query itself must be posed as a question

which llm are you using? And how you integrating this llm in ai search?

So its mean we cannot use ai search for this kind of questions which need to  like

provide me the average salary of all employee?
The ai search not retrieve all the salary of employees in sql table so llm model not able to calculate the average salary. Is this correct?


yes correct .Semantic search will only return verbatim statements from your index. It cannot calculate the average from tabular data.

Basically, in ai search when you do a query, it do the search on the fields which searchable and gives you the results according to the search score.
When you query on amount or salary it is of type integer and does not do search on that field. So, create index with filed salary or amount of type string.
Even if you are getting the average salary, that is only the average of the top documents retrieved.
If you see in advance settings, only 3-20 documents are retrieved

See this sample output
First i given prompt
give me details of price.

Gave the top 20 documents with values.

Then asked to calculate average.

It calculated for top 20 documents only not the whole records.
So, I recommend you query in such a way that it should filter out the records and gives documents based on the keyword and do whatever you want on top n documents.
Also remember it does search only on the field which are searchable.
